# Processing Image To Feed data in to Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am new to Machine Learning and recently took a courser by Andrew Ng on Coursera.
After that I shifted to Python and used Pandas, Numpy, Sklearn to implement ML algorithms.
Now while surfing I came across tensorFLow and found it pretty amazing, and implemented this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/) which takes MNIST data as input. 
Now I want to read my own custom images and use them for training. I am confused as to how should I convert the images to MNIST sort of data. Or some other way to train my Network. 
I took this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/) to create my network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on the MNIST dataset can be found on [Yann LeCun's website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

The TensorFlow module [tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.mnist_softmax.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py) looks to be acquiring/preparing the dataset for the train/test steps.

The MNIST dataset contains an image of a handwritten digit and a corresponding label. If you would like to create labels for a new image, you could use [scipy.misc.imread](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info.
I used [this](https://github.com/gskielian/JPG-PNG-to-MNIST-NN-Format) in order to convert my jpg to bytes array. Then used [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py) to convert it to MNIST form.
But in the first link why it converts any jpg images to png??? I did not get it, why not resize jpg tp jpg and use that instead. :?
   And secondly, on MNIST [website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) it says strange things, such as: "digits have been sizenormalized and centered in a fixedsize imag"

Comment: And this explanation on MNIST?
"The original black and white (bilevel) images from NIST were size normalized to fit in a 20x20 pixel box while preserving their aspect ratio. The resulting images contain grey levels as a result of the anti-aliasing technique used by the normalization algorithm. the images were centered in a 28x28 image by computing the center of mass of the pixels, and translating the image so as to position this point at the center of the 28x28 field.
With classification methods the error rate improves when the digits are centered by bounding box rather than center of mass."